# Why are my posts omitted from Google search results when my site is listed in it?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engine-indexing, search-results

My domain is not new at all, in fact I have waited for quite a long time now for Google to show some love. If I do a search for my domain name, it shows the website is listed, but if I try to search for even a year-old post on Google, using my website name too, it never returns it. Instead it says some results have been omitted and asks if those omitted results should be included in the search results.

The following is the message it returns:

> In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some
>   entries very similar to the 8 already displayed. If you like, you can repeat the search with the omitted results included.

Why are my posts are never returned in search results even though I have original and ample content on my website?

Comment: Sounds like Google considers  your site to be low quality

Comment: Sounds like you'll want to create a sitemap, add it so it registers on google webmaster tools, and compare the tracked pages to the full listing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is a case of "Only Google really know".

My thoughts:

Wordpress sites are going to generate several pages of duplicate content, eg tag pages, and so this type of page may be downgraded in the listings.

Your pages are heavy in template, but sometimes only a small area of content changes (such as the title and what video is playing).  As so little new content appears on some pages, this may make Google think the pages are more-or-less the same.

Oh, I'd be wary of using a .tk domain too.  That used to be the domain of spammers, as the domains were free.  It also suggests your site is based in Tokelau, New Zealand (I am assuming it is not).  This won't be causing this particular issue, but could potentially have other negative effects.

Comment: The link relates to Google search appliance, not relevant to web-search.

Comment: Yep, you're right.  Removed that reference.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do some SEO work on your site. Pages and blog posts need meaningful headers. Your h1 and h2  etc are important. Each pages header should be different.

An example of a problem might be an events page with an 'events' header. The detail may be loaded in by an Id on the querystring. This is bad practice for SEO. Each event should have its own meaningful header. Also words in the url are considered so having an id against a generic url is also a problem.

Get registered with webmaster tools. You might have 404s you aren't aware of lowering your site quality. The tools have lots of valuable details to help.

Submit a sitemap on webmaster tools too.

Comment: I did submit a sitemap on webmaster tools, it shows that 50% of URL's have been indexed since this morning, but I checked the source and I found  out all my posts a href = postlink have rel = nofollow attribute, does that make any difference? Do i need to worry about it?

Comment: [Google states that their engine takes "nofollow" literally and does not "follow" the link at all. However, experiments conducted by SEOs show conflicting results. These studies reveal that Google does follow the link, but it does not index the linked-to page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow)

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is pretty likely your site has an algorithmic 'penalty'.

The content is non-original low quality and a typical panda target. If you posted the same question in the Google Webmaster Forum, then I am sure you would be told much the same.

Some information on panda :

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/more-guidance-on-building-high-quality.html

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/another-step-to-reward-high-quality.html

Comment: :No, I have exactly just 2 copied posts and rest all of it, literally all of it is unique and original content.

Comment: Where I say unique, I mean not available elsewhere. 

There are hundreds of pages on the internet already telling people 'how to backup your wordpress blog'. Hundreds of free 'seo friendly' wordpress themes. Hundreds of posts on how to get 'Facebook likes'. You need to bring something new and not reheats of existing content. You have also titled and marketed your site as 'Techcrunch', Techcrunch you are not. You need to find & market your own identity and post content that is really valuable to searchers, useful to find.